# Get List of a tag in Selenium WebDriver using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, lambda

I want to get a list of a tag.

```
<div class="tags-section">
                    <h5 class="sidebar-section-title">Skills in this Class:</h5>
                        <a class="tag light initialized was-shown" href="/search?query=Adobe Illustrator&amp;via=class-details-about-page" data-ss-tag="adobe-illustrator" target="_blank" xpath="1" style="">Adobe Illustrator</a>
                        <a class="tag light initialized was-shown" href="/search?query=3D Design&amp;via=class-details-about-page" data-ss-tag="3d-design" target="_blank" xpath="2" style="">3D Design</a>
                        <a class="tag light initialized" href="/search?query=Graphic Design&amp;via=class-details-about-page" data-ss-tag="graphic-design" target="_blank" xpath="3" style="">Graphic Design</a>
                        <a class="tag light initialized" href="/search?query=Creative&amp;via=class-details-about-page" data-ss-tag="creative" target="_blank" xpath="4" style="">Creative</a>
                        <a class="tag light initialized" href="/search?query=3D&amp;via=class-details-about-page" data-ss-tag="3d" target="_blank" xpath="5">3D</a>
                        <a class="tag light initialized" href="/search?query=Vector Art&amp;via=class-details-about-page" data-ss-tag="vector-art" target="_blank" xpath="6">Vector Art</a>
                        <a class="tag light initialized" href="/search?query=Vector Graphics&amp;via=class-details-about-page" data-ss-tag="vector-graphics" target="_blank" xpath="7">Vector Graphics</a>
                </div>
```

I write the below code but I got an error.

```
                string[] myArray = web.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='tags-section']//a")).Select(x => x.Text).ToArray();
                string skill = string.Join(", ", myArray);
```

> Evaluation of method System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) calls into native method Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.GetFullPathName(char*, int, char*, System.IntPtr). Evaluation of native methods in this context is not supported.  string[]

**Update:**
I have to use the below code. But I still did not know why the above code not works.

```
            IList<IWebElement> collection = web.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='tags-section']//a"));
            string[] myArray = new string[collection.Count];
            int a = 0;
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                myArray[a++] = item.Text;
            }
```

Comment: FindElements returns `List<iWebElement>` not `string[ ]`. change it and try

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `string[] myArray = web.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.tags-section a")).Select(x => x.Text).ToArray();`

Comment: nothing changed. Xpath works correctly. I think the problem is lambda.

Answer (score -1):

Please give replace your path

```
List<WebElement> listOfElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div"));
```

You can use below by tag name

```
List<WebElement> listOfElements = table.findElements(By.tagName("your tagName"));
```

Then iterate on the listOfElements variable to further process

Comment: I think the problem is lambda. Xpath works correctly untill
`web.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='tags-section']//a"))`